# Cut function only working on some faces

Tags: modeling

I came into this problem already some times, and this time I decided to ask here if there's a solution to it.
Very easily, the cut function only works on some faces. The situation is practically identical, but there's no way to make it work on some faces, while on others there's no problem.
In the image, you can see that I have already cut (diagonal edges) other faces.
And you can see 2 polygons of 5 edges that there seem to be no way to cut.
I tried to merge the vertexes but everything is ok already.
[image]
The fun part is that if I don't cut to the vertex... it works.
[image]
[image]
Here is the file: [image]

Update: apparently after cutting the face, then the vertex becomes "visible" and cutting to it works.
[image]

Video: https://youtu.be/DiZhqcNZchI

Comment: all those 5 vertices are connected into 1 single face? Shading makes it looks like it's only quad with bottom vertice not being connected, but that is just a guess... could you share this piece of mesh with us?

Comment: They are a single face. I just removed the vertical edge all around the cylinder, so all those faces were subject to EXACTLY the same function. Blender "mistakes" the triangulation by choosing the shorter edge instead than choosing the less stretched triangle... so there's that extremely stretched triangle down there. And that's EXACTLY why I am manual cutting the triangles. I added the file, link at the end of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out that it is impossible in that setup, it is probably due to some error that doesn't allow it to be cut if there is something like this:
[image]

But, I have a different way for you to try to make parts like this... Try to use bridge edge loops, just select top loop and bottom loop like this, and press RMB and select Bridge edge loops:
[image]

It will essentially create what you are aiming for.
[image]

Comment: Cool, I'll try that, still better than retriangulate everything! Thank you!

Comment: It is a good feature that works best if you have the same or half of the vertices on one side like this... If you have one loop with 50 vertices and 1 with 4 it will make a lot of messy triangles, if you make 2 loops with same amount of verts it will make quads, if there are half of vertices on one loop, it will create this nice pattern in the answer

Comment: Yeah, I know the bridge function in Max but it worked quite messily and I didn't think of using it in this case just because it wasn't my habit to use it in Max, due to its uselessness. But in Blender it seems to be really well done.
However, in my opinion, the cut function can be refined a bit to address these situations. This is not the first time this happens to me. Must say that at least it doesn't introduce double vertexes, but still... this last buggo could be polished!

Comment: I mean, if you think that it is a bug worth of report, you can always report a bug to devs